# Angular para criação de layout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular, typescript

Bom dia galera!

Estou começando estudar agora angular, node e typescript (não nessa ordem) e me surgiram as seguintes dúvidas:

1- Notei que para executar o angular, normalmente se utiliza o node para apps backend por exemplo. Vi que da pra criar layouts com o angular, sendo assim, como faço para executar um projeto pelo chrome? (por ex exportar o proj pra um server sem node)

2-Utilizando o angular e node, o PHP não teria mais necessidade em um projeto?

3- Com essas 3 linguagens, considerando que sou mediano em javascript, por onde devo começar?

Fico no aguardo com a colaboração de vcs :D

Comment: Bom dia, da uma pesquisada em mean stack, é uma alternativa vc faz tudo com angular, node, etc..

Comment: @Guilherme Obrigado pela dica, vou estudar sobre!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes.

> 1- Notei que para executar o angular, normalmente se utiliza o node para apps backend por exemplo. Vi que da pra criar layouts com o angular, sendo assim, como faço para executar um projeto pelo chrome? (por ex exportar o proj pra um server sem node)

Você precisa de um servidor WEB para publicar a aplicação. A aplicação angular poderia ficar hospedada em um servidor apache mesmo.
Quanto a utilização do node no backend, não é uma obrigatoriedade, na minha empresa anterior utilizávamos angular e C# no backend, é uma questão que depende da necessidade da empresa e escolha da linguagem da empresa, o frontend em angular não tem nada a ver com a linguagem escolhida para o backend.

> 2-Utilizando o angular e node, o PHP não teria mais necessidade em um projeto?

Sim, se você usar o node no backend o PHP é dispensável, mas caso você prefira pode criar um projeto com o PHP no backend e o angular no frontend, basta você ter uma API. O Mesmo serve para caso você queira utilizar C#, Java, Python, Ruby, etc.

> 3- Com essas 3 linguagens, considerando que sou mediano em javascript,
>   por onde devo começar?

Aprende javascript primeiro e depois estuda o framework, seja angular, react ou qualquer outro. 
Após aprender bem javascript, cria um foco pra ti, caso você prefira trabalhar com frontend, comece a estudar o angular, caso goste mais do backend, estude  node.